# Scala Function1<T,U> becomes Function1<Object,Object> in Java

Tags: java, scala, generics

I am trying to use the Deequ library from Java, and am having issue using the following method:

```
  def hasCompleteness(
      column: String,
      assertion: Double => Boolean,
      hint: Option[String] = None)
    : CheckWithLastConstraintFilterable = {
    addFilterableConstraint { filter => completenessConstraint(column, assertion, filter, hint) }
  }
```

In particular, for the assertion, I need to pass in a `Function1<Double, Boolean>`

So I use the following code to create an assertion function in Java:

```
public static Function1<Double, Boolean> atLeast(double thresholdPercentage) {
  return new scala.compat.java8.functionConverterImpls.FromJavaFunction<>((Double actualPercentage) -> actualPercentage >= thresholdPercentage);
}
```

Simple enough, right?

Only, my Java Class now won't compile because the signature of the `hasCompleteness` method, when viewed *from Java* is that the assertion parameter is a `Function1<Object, Object>`. Thus I see the following error:

```
Required type: Function1<Object, Object>
Provided: Function1<Double, Boolean>
```

If I change my `atLeast` method to return an unparametrized `Function1` the issue goes away, but this feels like an ugly kludge.

Am I condemned to losing the type params when using this method from Java? Or is there something perhaps wrong with my IntelliJ / Gradle setup causing this weird behavior?

Comment: Sounds not normal behaviour to me. At compile time there's no reason for those types to disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

peterz detailed exactly what happens under the hood.

Sounds like what you need is an explicit conversion from the primitive `double` Java predicate (`java.util.function.DoublePredicate`) to the `scala.Double` Scala predicate (`Double => Boolean`).

Scala actually offers one such conversion called `FromJavaDoublePredicate`.
The code does not require explicit `Double` cast anymore:

```
  /* some scala file */
  def hasCompleteness(
      x: Double,
      f: Double => Boolean
  ): Unit = println(f(x))

  /* some java file */
  public static FromJavaDoublePredicate atLeast(double thresholdPercentage) {
      return new scala.compat.java8.functionConverterImpls.FromJavaDoublePredicate(
        actualPercentage -> actualPercentage >= thresholdPercentage);
  }

  FromJavaDoublePredicate f = atLeast(3.0);
  Test.hasCompleteness(5, f);  // true
```

PS. From what I saw, you chose [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat), so I assumed you use an earlier version of Scala. Their maintainers state:

> If you are using Scala 2.13 or newer only, then don't use this
> library! Use the classes under `scala.jdk` instead; they were added to
> the standard library in 2.13.

So for Scala 2.13.x I recommend using the [FromJavaDoublePredicate](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.8/scala/jdk/FunctionWrappers$$FromJavaDoublePredicate.html) case class in the `FunctionWrappers` object instead.

Comment: Thanks! And yes unfortunately I'm locked to Scala 2.12 for now, so it's the java8-compat library I must use. Appreciate the explanation and the workaround. I see it's impossible to return a `Function1<Double, Boolean>` given the way the types are lost when reading from Java, but at least I can use `FromJavaDoublePredicate`

Answer (score 3):

That seems how Scala compiler translates "primitive" Scala types (remember, `Double` here is `scala.Double` and not `java.lang.Double`). E.g. Scala declarations

```
  var d: Double => Boolean;
  var s: String => String;
```

produce (as shown by javap):

```
  public abstract scala.Function1<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> d();
  public abstract scala.Function1<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> s();
```

Note how `Double` and `Boolean` both translate to `Object`, but `String` is preserved

Comment: Got it! Wish they played more nicely together, but at least this helps validate that I'm not crazy / my IDE isn't broken. Thank you!